# iOS app for alphabets with sound clips

Tags: ios, xcode6

I am developing an iOS app which contains A to Z alphabets. I have sound clips for each alphabet. I have a button "next", which changes alphabet on click. Now I want the particular sound clip of particular alphabet to play when I click next button..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { 
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    NSURL * soundURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"apple" withExtension:@"mp3"];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)CFBridgingRetain(soundURL), &fruitsound); 
}

- (IBAction)btnPlayClicked:(id)sender {
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(fruitsound); 
}
```

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    NSURL * soundURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"apple" withExtension:@"mp3"];
    
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)CFBridgingRetain(soundURL), &fruitsound);
}- (IBAction)btnPlayClicked:(id)sender {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(fruitsound);
    

} @luk2302

Comment: The above code plays only a single sound clip @luk2302

Comment: I know, have you tried passing in something dynamic instead of the static `@"apple"`?

Comment: yes i know that...i have around 26 sound clips ... i am not getting how to do it... is there anyway or method or something to do it ? not a pro in iOS , in learning process. @luk2302

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a way to convert the letter they have tapped into the sound you want to play. The easiest way to do this is to just name the sound file exactly the same as the letter ;) There are other more complicated (but better in other ways) to solve this problem, but to get you started try something like this :

```
- (IBAction)btnPlayClicked:(UIbutton)sender {
    // Get the letter from the button that was tapped and use that as the sound file name
    NSString *letter = sender.text.lowercaseString;
    NSURL *soundURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:letter withExtension:@"mp3"];

    // Create the sound with that name and play it
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)CFBridgingRetain(soundURL), &fruitsound);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(fruitsound); 
}
```

Assuming you've named your sounds a.mp3, b.mp3 etc this should work.

However, I don't know what / where `fruitsound` is defined, so you might have a memory leak somewhere? If you do, you know which site to ask about it on ;)

Comment: Fruitsound is nothing but ths...{ SystemSoundID fruitsound;} in .h file

Comment: You probably need to call `AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID` at some point? I've never used the AudioServices... stuff but a quick look at the docs makes me think you need to destroy each resource you create. You should also run your app through the Analyzer (from in the Product menu) to see if it flags any warnings.